# Monitor not receiving any picture data from computer?

Tags: macos, mac, display, troubleshooting

I cannot get a picture to display on a monitor for my Mac computer.

I formatted the hard drives (couple passes with 1's and 0's) and now I cannot get the monitor to display a picture. I know the computer, hard drive, and monitor work.

The mac makes the start-up chime and responds to key commands. I can open the CD tray with a bootup command, boot from CD, etc. I tried resetting the NVRAM and still nothing.

It sounds like it boots properly and I can hear the fan and computer running and it responds to input but there is no picture on the monitor. It is just a black screen.

The monitor power button is orange instead of blue and when I turn it off and on it just says "Entering Power Save Mode" and then goes black screen again.

Even if I try to start a hardware test there is no picture. I can plug the monitor in to another computer and it works fine and the computer was working as well until I formatted it.